# Trying to remove a Computer Object from AD security group using powershell & importing from a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

having a heck of a time with this. Also, wanted to preface this with I'm not the best at PowerShell as I'm just starting out. I have a CSV file that I'm trying to read the first column which happens to be 'AssetName'. These are AD joined computers.

```
#Get Computer
$Computers = Import-csv -Delimiter ";" -Path 'C:\Path\to\File.csv'  | Select-Object AssetName
$Group = "Sec Group Name"

# Set the ErrorActionPreference to SilentlyContinue, because the -ErrorAction 
# option doesn't work with Get-ADComputer or Get-ADGroup.
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

# Get the computer and group from AD to make sure they are valid.
$ComputerObject = Get-ADComputer $Computer
$GroupObject = Get-ADGroup $Group

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
    if ($GroupObject) {
        # If both the computer and the group exist, remove the computer from 
        # the group.
        Remove-ADGroupMember $Group `
            -Members (Get-ADComputer $Computer).DistinguishedName -Confirm:$False
        Write-Host " "
        Write-Host "The computer, ""$Computer"", has been removed from the group, ""$Group""." `
            -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host " "
    }
    else {
        Write-Host " "
        Write-Host "I could not find the group, ""$Group"", in Active Directory." `
            -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host " "
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "I could not find the computer, $Computer, in Active Directory." `
        -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host " "
}
```

Upon doing so, I want to remove that Asset from a specific security group. Whenever I run my script, I get this error. I don't know why it's reading it with the "@{AssetName=CompName}".

The computer, "@{AssetName=CompName}", has been removed from the group, "Sec Group Name".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, update your code to reflect how it actually is, currently you have `Get-ADComputer $Computer` outside the loop and `$Computer` is not defined outside the loop, that would already throw a different error. In addition, `Select-Object AssetName` should be `Select-Object -Expand AssetName`

Comment: Ah I see now. I've made the changes suggested and it's working as expected now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With your first line you are saving a list of PSObjects to $Computers.

```
$Computers = Import-csv -Delimiter ";" -Path 'C:\Path\to\File.csv'  | Select-Object AssetName
```

These Objects look like this `@{AssetName=Computername}`

When you iterate these objects you need to specify that you only want the value of the AssetName parameter

```
Get-ADComputer $Computer.AssetName
```

Another (in my opinion better) way would be to stop using Select-Object (which storing the returned objects in $computers) and only storing a list of AssetNames in $computers like this:

```
$Computers = (Import-csv -Delimiter ";" -Path 'C:\Path\to\File.csv').AssetName
```

EDIT:
You can also use -ExpandProperty with your Select-Object:

```
$Computers = Import-csv -Delimiter ";" -Path 'C:\Path\to\File.csv'  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AssetName
```